# Markov Chain Expected Value notation.

Tags: markov-chains, conditional-expectation

I have  question to answer regarding $X_n$ where $X_n$ is a Markov chain, $n$=$0$,$1$,$2$,...

I am loking for  [image]

What I don't understand is what this $3$ on $X_{n+1}$ is! Any ideas?

Comment: in probability you never know for sure, but probably it's $X_{n+1}\cdot X_{n+1}\cdot X_{n+1}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$E((X_{n+1})^3\mid X_n)\text{}$$

Comment: How can we compute the above?

Comment: This depends on the Markov chain and should be the subject of another question, if any.